# Flutter NFC read and write at same time

Tags: flutter, plugins, nfc

I'm using currently the [nfc_in_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_in_flutter) plugin for reading/writing nfc tag. I tried to do something like, first read the nfc tag then write it in the same screen, but (in Android) the native nfc reader pop up and override everything.(I mean in the next read, the native stuff coming...).
So is there any solution for first read and then write without the native stuff?

Comment: Show your code, this will help people work out why the Native reader pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure why the native reader pops up. But have you read this from the documentation section? Try using the write method while keeping the read stream from the package open.

---

**Note that the read stream must still be open when the .write method is called. This means that the once argument in .readNDEF() cannot be used.**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it, it was my fault(obviously) that the native stuff comes in. I stopped the stream... I think this will solve everything.